# Django: I want to display the data of current month but i have not found a working query for it. Please assist

Tags: django, django-views

Django: I want to display the data of current month but i have not found a working query for it. Please assist. Following is the code for models.py and views.py

Views.py

```
def paymentfullreportarchived(request):
    date=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    allpayments=Payment.objects.filter(Date=date,Status="Archived").order_by('-Date')   
    total= Payment.objects.filter(Date=date,Status="Archived").order_by('-Date').aggregate(Sum('Amount')).get('Amount__sum') or 0
    context={
        'payment':'active',
        'allpayments':allpayments,
        'date':date,
        'total':total,
    }
    return render(request,'paymentfullreportarchived.html',context)
```

Models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    Date=models.DateField()
    User=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PatientName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Dentist=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Scheme=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PaymentMethod=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Amount=models.FloatField()
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="Pending")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the date filters

```
start_month=datetime.date( 2021, 10, 1)
end_month  =datetime.date( 2021, 10, 31)
...Payment.objects.filter( Date__range=[start_month, end_month] )
```

or

```
 year=2021
 month=10
 ...Payment.objects.filter( Date__year=year, Date__month=month )
```

Also i *strongly* recommend sticking with the conventions. Model fields should be lowercase `date` not uppercase `Date` as you are using.

Comment: That is a static answer. I want to show the data of current month mean It can be any from 12 months.

Comment: So do some `datetime.date.today()` manipulation based on the current date to get the first and last of the month you are interested in. That's a Python datetime question not a Django question.

Comment: I think you are reading data as date?